# Is it possible to use placeholders ${} for a property KEY in a spring-boot application.yaml or properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, property-placeholder

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the placeholder replacement not only in values but also for the key in a spring-boot `application.yaml` (or .properties).

For example:

```
  openapi:
    security:
      - my-resource
        - ${some.path.role-a}
        - ${some.path.role-b}
```

Work's like a charm, nothing special here.
But what if I need to grab the "my-resource" also from a "placeholder"?
Is that possible?

Already tried different ways like:

```
  openapi:
    security:
      - ${some.path.resource}
        - ${some.path.role-a}
        - ${some.path.role-b}
```

or

```
  openapi:
    security:
      - "${some.path.resource}"
        - ${some.path.role-a}
        - ${some.path.role-b}
```

But everything yields to just the variable name as the key.